# How to show/convert oData weblink to UIImage in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, image, odata

I am getting image from microsoft account by using this api :
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/photo

And this api gets this data which is shown in output. But i don't know how to show this link into image in Swift.

Output :

```
"@odata.context" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('rahulchopra.93%40outlook.com')/photo/$entity";
"@odata.mediaContentType" = "image/jpeg";
height = 2;
id = 2X2;
width = 2;
```

Comment: do you want to show this image from url in imageview?

Comment: Yeah, i want to show the image on UIImageView

Comment: did you find your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Create extension of UIImageView

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloaded(from url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.image = image
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    func downloaded(from link: String, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        downloaded(from: url, contentMode: mode)
    }
}
```

and Use like this

```
imageView.downloaded(from: "http://www.apple.com/euro/ios/ios8/a/generic/images/og.png")
```